# Smoking battery when jumping from another car

Tags: battery, acura, mdx

Smoking battery when jumping it and when I tried charging it the voltage meter kept jumping up n Down. Also while the vehicle was running it just completely died on my 2005 Acura MDX. Does anyone know what may cause this. But when I took the battery out of the truck and tried charging it. It didn’t do that. Can this be electrical?
It first started getting the jumper cables to get hot n started smoking

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You are saying it was "smoking" while charging inside the vehicle (I take it the vehicle was running and you were charging it off of the alternator)?

Comment: Is the meter on the charger actually a *current* (not voltage) meter?  Sounds  like when the battery is mounted in your car there's almost a short circuit from the positive terminal to the ground. Was the battery touched (removed and replaced say) prior to your first having trouble?

Comment: No I meant smoking when I tried to jump it t

Comment: @paulster2 When I tried to charge it with battery charger the voltage meter jumped up n down. But when I tried to jump the battery with another vehicle the cables got hot and the connection to battery started to smoke

Comment: Battery charger @mike65535

Comment: If the jumper cables (and other things) were getting hot it means there's a LOT of current being drawn. This means either 1) there's a (near) short in the battery or car, or 2) you are hooking up the charging cables backwards. They are supposed to go plus-to-plus and minus-to-minus.  (Ignore cable colors)

Comment: @Mike65535 no the cables r on positive on positive. I’ve jumped many vehicles I know to look . Thank you for that though.

Comment: Was there any repair work done on the car recently - prior to your first having to jump it?

Comment: Mike65535 It’s a 2005 Acura MDX I just bought it from a family friend n her son SAYS! he replaced the  condenser n it just needed to be charged but now the blower for the air just keeps running . So I took the truck I didn’t want him working on it anymore.